# Table AutoFitBehavior does not work in Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

i am trying to develop a print function in my Java Swing Desktop Application. All i need is a basic printing, so there is no need of an external library or something. My app, is only for windows, so there is nothing to stop me for using a VBS file in order to generate a Word (.docx) document and just print it.

The thing is that i need to print a table. My app generates, the following script (ignore the fields, texts and etc).

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
objWord.Visible = False
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

Set objSection = objDoc.Sections(1)
objDoc.Sections(1).Footers(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 0
objDoc.Sections(1).Footers(1).Range.Bold = True
objDoc.Sections(1).Footers(1).Range.Text = ""


objSelection.Font.Bold = True
objSelection.Font.Underline = True
objSelection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1
objSelection.Font.Size = "14"
objSelection.TypeText "I am a title"
objSelection.TypeParagraph()
objSelection.Font.Underline = False

objSelection.Font.Size = "12"
Const NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 2
Const NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 4
Set objRange = objDoc.Range()
objrange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd 
objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, NUMBER_OF_ROWS, NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)
objTable.Style = "Πλέγμα Πίνακα" 'Greek MS Word needs style name on greek. "Table Grid" is the english one
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Description"
objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Date"
objTable.Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Count"
objTable.Cell(1, 4).Range.Text = "Notes"


objTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "Hello there i am"+Chr(13)+"a big text"+Chr(13)+"but i am far bigger than you"
objTable.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = "10/11/2018"
objTable.Cell(2, 3).Range.Text = "10.000"
objTable.Cell(2, 4).Range.Text = "nothing here"

objSelection.Tables(1).Select
objSelection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

objDoc.SaveAs("C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Temp\AAA - 13213908551013013192846.docx")

objWord.Quit
```

With this script, i get [image: this table]

What i want to achieve is: [image: this.]

In order to get the table which is in the second image, i did the following steps from MS Word. *Right click in the table - > Auto Adjust - > Auto Adjust with the contents*, then again, *Right click in the table - > Auto Adjust -> Auto Adjust in the window*.

So, i guessed recording these steps via "Create Macro" action from MS Word will give me the answer. It "gave" me these lines:

```
objSelection.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitContent)
objSelection.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
```

I added them in my script, right before "Save as..." but there is not any changes to the table. So....I was wondering, is there anything more should i  do, or do i do something wrong? I am not familiar with VBA.

OS: Windows 10 x64

MS-Office: Microsoft Office Professional Plus **2016**

**EDIT - Answer**:

```
objSelection.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (1) 'word VBA does not support enumerations
objSelection.Tables(1).Rows.Alignment = 1
```

Comment: Put them before the collapse statement

Comment: @Freeflow i have already tried to do it. The result is the same.

Comment: I tried 
objSelection.Tables(1).Select
objSelection.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitContent)
objSelection.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
objSelection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

and it adjusts the size of the table just fine on my PC Office 365 64 bit Word 2016.

Comment: @Freeflow Could you upload the full code in pastebin? Also did you try this specific text content as mine? Also, how do you run the script? Maybe inside from MS-Word it has different behavior than double-clicking on it.

Comment: I used the code you posted with a few minor adjustments to the first few lines to use the active document as the source for objDoc.  The code ran in Word VBA.

Comment: @Freeflow So maybe this is the problem? Because i only double click on the .vbs file and i get the generated .docx file.

Comment: Maybe you should remove the VBA and Word-vba tags if your code is vbscript.  I tried your code in vbscript and can confirm that the table does not autofit.

Comment: On further investigation I found that vbscript does not use the Word enumerations so the wdAutofitXXXX enumerations are being translated as 0 and the autofit behaviour is wdAutoFitFixed..  If you change wdAutoFitContent to 1  or wdAutoFitWidow to 2 the table should auto fit.  BUT, you only need one of those lines.

Comment: @Freeflow Thanks. It seems this was the problem, and for some reason i never think about it . I just need to center the table after that.

Comment: The same caveat will apply.  You'll need to use an integer constant and not the enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the widths of the columns yourself. Something like this perhaps:

```
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)

With objTable
    .Style = "Πλέγμα Πίνακα"
    .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
    .PreferredWidth = 100
    .Columns(1).Width = 40
    .Columns(2).Width = 20
    .Columns(3).Width = 15
    .Columns(4).Width = 25
    .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Description"
    .Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Date"
    .Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Count"
    .Cell(1, 4).Range.Text = "Notes"
    .Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "Hello there i am"+Chr(13)+"a big text"+Chr(13)+"but i am far bigger than you"
    .Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = "10/11/2018"
    .Cell(2, 3).Range.Text = "10.000"
    .Cell(2, 4).Range.Text = "nothing here"
    .AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
End With
```

You wil have to experiment with the percentages of course before you think it looks good..

Comment: What i get is this. https://i.imgur.com/JyKcDvG.png Working with percentage could work for me, but as it seems it does not work either.

Comment: Sizing the columns in a Word table seems like a nightmare.. I'm not sure, but perhaps you need to set the `.PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent` for each column aswell, so `.Columns(1).PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent` .. `.Columns(4).PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent`